# Does this inequality hold and why?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x,y,z$ be real valued functions that are defined and continuous on an interval $[a,b]$.

From the triangle inequality it is true that $|x(t)-z(t)+z(t)-y(t)|\le |x(t)-z(t)|+|z(t)-y(t)|$.

But does that mean that $\int\limits_a^b |x(t)-z(t)+z(t)-y(t)|\,dt\le \int\limits_a^b |x(t)-z(t)|+|z(t)-y(t)|\,dt$ is true?

Comment: If $f,g \in L_1(\mu)$ and $f \le g$ almost everywhere then $\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu \le \int g \,\mathrm{d}\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because both integrands are nonnegative in $[a,b]$

We do not even need this ; as Paolo mentioned , $f(x)\le g(x)$ is enough.

The difference between the integrals over $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ is the integral over $g(x)-f(x)$.

This must be nonnegative because $g(x)-f(x)$ is nonnegative for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as Peter answered, if you want ot be more persuaded think that we have:
$$
|{x(t)-z(t)}| + |{z(t)-y(t)}| - |{x(t)-z(t)+z(t)-y(t)}| \ge 0
$$
And hence
$$
\int_a^b({|{x(t)-z(t)}| + |{z(t)-y(t)}| - |{x(t)-z(t)+z(t)-y(t)}|})dt \ge 0
$$
Then due to additiveness of integrals
$$
\int_a^b{({|{x(t)-z(t)}| + |{z(t)-y(t)}|})dt} -  \int_a^b{(|{x(t)-z(t)+z(t)-y(t)}|)dt} \ge 0
$$

From which your result follows.

Hope I helped.